# cell property reset after cell dequeued?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have made a custom cell with a UISwitch in it.

The custom cell class has the property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL boolValue;
```

The important part of the cell initalization reads:

```
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    UISwitch *boolSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
    boolSwitch.on = self.boolValue;
        //self.boolValue = boolSwithch.on /** tried as well **/
    [boolSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.accessoryView = boolSwitch;
}
return self;
```

and the switched: method:

```
- (void)switched:(id)boolSwitch {
    self.boolValue = ((UISwitch *)boolSwitch).on;
}
```

Now this all works great, I can get hold of the `boolValue` from the tableview delegates no problem, that is unless I say present a modal view after rocking the switch. When I return to the tableView, the `cell.boolValue` will once again be set to its default (NO).

Although the visual state of the switch itself remains correct, the cell property does not.

I think the property is not persisting after being dequeued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persisting a value should be the job of a backing model object, and not the cell itself.  The same cell object can be reused multiple times by a table view, and you always want to set its proper state in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` from the backing object.  This way, the reused cell could have had `boolValue` set to `YES` or `NO` previously but you would always set `cell.boolSwitch.on` to `modelObject.someBoolProperty` and end up in the proper state.

Your `switched:` method is where you would update the state of the backing object:

```
- (void)switched:(UISwitch*)boolSwitch {
    self.modelObject.someBoolProperty = boolSwitch.on;
}
```